# Getting debconf-set-selections right for scripted install of phpMyAdmin

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, phpmyadmin

I'm setting up a Vagrant box on my MacBook Pro (again, because the transition to Apple Silicon changed a lot), with Ubuntu 20.04 as the guest OS. I'm trying to do it all using provisioning scripts, and that has all gone fine until I get to installing phpMyAdmin.

Previously the script I had would install phpMyAdmin without user interaction, using a username and password from arguments passed by the `Vagrantfile`. That script no longer works (and is hopelessly lost because I'm a bit bad at versioning). Here is what I currently have, which stalls (I have to kill the `Vagrant` process on my Mac before being able to `vagrant halt` and rollback to last snapshot) partway though the phpMyAdmin install...

```
#!/bin/sh

# 09 Install phpMyAdmin

# Variables...
# 1 - PMA_USERNAME      = ⚠️ See Vagrantfile
# 2 - PMA_PASSWORD      = ⚠️ See Vagrantfile
# 3 - REMOTE_FOLDER     = "/var/www"

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Add repository for phpMyAdmin
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 sudo apt-add-repository -yu ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa

# Call the vm_upgrade.sh script
/var/www/provision/scripts/vm_upgrade.sh

# Set phpMyAdmin database user and password for debconf selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver multiselect apache2" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install boolean true"             | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/db/app-user string $1"                     | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass password $2"                | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm password $2"          | sudo debconf-set-selections

# Install phpMyAdmin
sudo apt -qy install phpmyadmin

# Remove the default phpMyAdmin directory
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/phpmyadmin

# Copy phpMyAdmin to the specified folder
sudo cp -R $3/provision/html/phpmyadmin $3/html/phpmyadmin

# Set permissions
sudo chmod -R 755 $3/html/phpmyadmin

# Enable mbstring
sudo phpenmod mbstring

# Restart Apache to apply changes
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

If I knock out or delete `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` & all the `sudo debconf-set-selections` lines, the installer runs with normal user interaction. There I accept 2 defaults (because I'm using Apache), then enter & confirm a password. The username is preset as `phpmyadmin`. That's exactly the same as installing it manually in a `vagrant ssh` session, which is how I have installed phpMyAdmin and moved on.

Now I've decided to change some details at an earlier stage, which provides opportunity to get this bit right. Can anyone tell me how to get `debconf-set-selections` right for phpMyAdmin?

Comment: For those concerned about security, yes, there is a username & password in cleartext in my Vagrantfile. However it only needs to be there for just long enough to call this script.